# Quarkus JWT authentication doesn't work as a native app

Tags: quarkus, graalvm, quarkus-oidc

I created a new Quarkus app using the following command:

```
mvn io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.13.7.Final:create \
    -DprojectGroupId=com.okta.rest \
    -DprojectArtifactId=quarkus \
    -DclassName="com.okta.rest.quarkus.HelloResource" \
    -Dpath="/hello" \
    -Dextensions="smallrye-jwt"
```

Then, I modified the generated `HelloResource` to print out the user's name.

```java
package com.okta.rest.quarkus;

import io.quarkus.security.Authenticated;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext;
import java.security.Principal;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/")
    @Authenticated
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello(@Context SecurityContext context) {
        Principal userPrincipal = context.getUserPrincipal();
        return "Hello, " + userPrincipal.getName() + "!";
    }

}
```

To make this work with Okta, I added a couple of properties to `application.properties`:

```
mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location=https://dev-1309757.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/keys
mp.jwt.verify.issuer=https://dev-1309757.okta.com/oauth2/default
```

I fixed the `HelloResourceTest` so it expects a 401 now.

```java
package com.okta.rest.quarkus;

import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;

@QuarkusTest
public class HelloResourceTest {

    @Test
    public void testHelloEndpoint() {
        given()
          .when().get("/hello")
          .then()
             .statusCode(401);
    }

}
```

Then, I ran `./mvnw quarkus:dev`. I'm able to generate a valid access token using [OIDC Debugger](https://oidcdebugger.com) and access this API using HTTPie.

```
http :8080/hello Authorization:"Bearer $TOKEN"
```

Response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 28
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8

Hello, matt.raible@okta.com!
```

However, if I build it as a native image using `./mvnw package -Pnative` and try to run it, I'm unable to access the API.

I'm not sure if the `Unable to get GraalVM version` error is something to be worried about when building.

```
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:1.13.7.Final:build (default) @ quarkus ---
[INFO] [org.jboss.threads] JBoss Threads version 3.2.0.Final
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.JarResultBuildStep] Building native image source jar: /Users/mraible/graalvm-java/quarkus/target/quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar/quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep] Building native image from /Users/mraible/graalvm-java/quarkus/target/quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar/quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
[ERROR] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep] Unable to get GraalVM version from the native-image binary.
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildRunner] /Users/mraible/.sdkman/candidates/java/21.1.0.r11-grl/bin/native-image ...
```

Running `./target/quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner` starts everything just fine.

```
2021-06-14 16:19:10,616 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) quarkus 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT native (powered by Quarkus 1.13.7.Final) started in 0.020s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080
2021-06-14 16:19:10,617 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile prod activated.
2021-06-14 16:19:10,617 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi, mutiny, resteasy, security, smallrye-context-propagation, smallrye-jwt, vertx, vertx-web]
```

However, I'm unable to access the `/hello` endpoint with a valid access token.

```
$ http :8080/hello Authorization:"Bearer $TOKEN"
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
content-length: 0
www-authenticate: Bearer {token}
```

If I stop the native app and run `./mvnw quarkus:dev`, the same command works.

```
$ http :8080/hello Authorization:"Bearer $TOKEN"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 28
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8

Hello, matt.raible@okta.com!
```

Comment: Hi Matt, can you please add this log config: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jwt#how-to-check-the-errors-in-the-logs.

Comment: This test, https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/integration-tests/smallrye-jwt-token-propagation/src/main/resources/application.properties,  also fetches the verification keys from the remote JWK endpoint and it runs in the native mode. Quarkus JWT demo also runs in a native mode but it uses the local keys - so not sure yet where the problem is

Comment: I've just run a Quarkus JWT quickstart in a native mode, keys are fetched from Keycloak, token obtained with the help of OIDC debugger, and all works with curl. Please have a look at the logs, I wonder what will be shown there

Comment: Thanks for the tip on how to turn up logging. When I do, I see the error is related to HTTPS. `Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Accessing an URL protocol that was not enabled. The URL protocol https is supported but not enabled by default. It must be enabled by adding the --enable-url-protocols=https option to the native-image command.`

Comment: Someone else suggested that it might be an SSL problem and referred me to https://quarkus.io/guides/native-and-ssl. It seems like one easy workaround would be to add something like the OAuth2 extension. Is there a better way to enable TLS?

Comment: I was able to solve this by adding `<quarkus.native.additional-build-args>--enable-url-protocols=https</quarkus.native.additional-build-args>` to the `native` profile's properties in `pom.xml`. If you post your logging suggestion as an answer with this additional tip, I'll accept it!

Comment: Sounds good, see also https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/17929, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please enable the [quarkus-smallrye-jwt TRACE logging](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jwt#how-to-check-the-errors-in-the-logs) to see why the tokens are rejected.
And indeed, as you have also found out, `https` protocol needs to be enabled in the native image, which can be done, as you have shown :-), by adding `<quarkus.native.additional-build-args>--enable-url-protocols=https</quarkus.native.additional-build-args>` to the native profile's properties in `pom.xml`.

[This PR](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/17929) will ensure adding it manually won't be required.

thanks

Comment: Thanks for creating a PR to add this! It's great to see it'll be in the next release. 